# Why does the toolbar have spaces?

Tags: android, toolbar

[image]

Why is space here?

This is xml code.

```
   <Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    >
...

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</Toolbar>
```

Also, I tried app:contentInsetRight and app:contentInsetEnd. But It got an error.

Comment: Consider posing your whole XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Its to avoid the overlapping of the toolbar by the system windows(i.e. navigation bar and status bar). You could also remove the contentInsets and use android:fitsSystemWindows = "true".